# How can I find an html element with always changing id through XPATH?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I ve run into a problem with my web automation. I have a drop down menu with two clickable Options. the id (picture ref.) changes every time that I load onto the page due to the element being created manually each time beforehand.

[image][image]

The "-1" and "-0" definition stays the same tho. Is there any possible way to get xpath to only look onto the "-1" and "-0" in the id?

Current code:

```
folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ng-select[@placeholder='Choose Key Set..']")
folder.click()

element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='a0cb2db88cfe-1']"))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

folder = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='a0cb2db88cfe-1']")
folder.click()
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code should work, But I have not tried yet.

> for -0 it should be - //div[1][@class='ng-option ng-star-inserted']
>
> for -1 it should be - //div[2][@class='ng-option ng-star-inserted']

Please try this and let me know the status

Comment: Interesting approach, tried a few versions of it but it doesn't find the element... gonna proceed trying tho

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out the proper way to locate the html element, but here is my solution over an offset click:

```
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ng-select[@placeholder='Choose Key Set..']"), 0,0)
actions.move_by_offset(100, 81).click().perform()
```

Comment: Btw guys if you get a `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` then import your action chain newly each time! Spent 5 hours finding this one out :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it changes only a part of the **id** value, you can try to locate elements by constant value part.
Just try to use these CSS ones:

```
"[role='option'] [id*='-0']"
"[role='option'] [id*='-1']"
```